# Does the ASUS Micro ATX PRIME B550M-K motherboard support Ryzens 5xxx series out of the box?

Tags: processor, motherboard, memory, compatibility

I hope you can guide me, there is the motherboard

- `ASUS Micro ATX PRIME B550M-K`
  based on the AM4 socket, the idea is to pair it with a Ryzen 3/5/7 5xxx. But since the majority of the motherboards needs to update the agesa microcodes to be able to handle the 5xxx series. Im in doubt if this device needs to be flashed or not. It's expected to buy a bunch, so it would be a good idea to be sure it can.

Based on the official [specs](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/PRIME/PRIME-B550M-K/techspec/) it is supposed to do so.
But in several pages like [this](https://www.newegg.com/asus-prime-b550m-k/p/N82E16813119330), can't cofirm the capacity or it's marked as update needed (plus several comments here and there contradictories, someone says no and there someone says yes). As of today, I'm not aware of any motherboard that support it without flashing (this makes me wonder if the official info is right or its a bait to buy this).

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That motherboard does not support ryzen 5000 out of the box, and also does not support BIOS flashback, so if you want to get ryzen 5000 working, you need an extra cpu, ram and gpu to flash the bios.

The AsRock B550 PG Riptide does support ryzen 5000 out of the box

Comment: Thanks for your answer, by chance do you know of other motherboards able to do it?, My local retailers does not have these model, they have the B550M Pro4,  ATX B550 Extreme4 and the  ATX B550 TAICHI.

Comment: I don't know about those, I have to do some research for that

Comment: But there are others that are able to run that